# How does this print syntax work? print('something', ['a', 'list'][boolean])

Tags: python, printing, boolean

```
print('something', ['a', 'list'][boolean])
```

Depending on the boolean value this either prints, a or list.

I have never seen this notation before and am wondering how it works.

Comment: What's `boolean`? Is it meant to be a stand-in for `True` or `False`?

Comment: Yes, stands for True or False.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Python's `bool` is a subclass of `int`, where `True` is 1 and `False` is 0. 
   `isinstance(True, int) # True`
2. As such, booleans can be used as indexes. `['a', 'list'][boolean]` evaluates to 
   `['a', 'list'][0]` if `boolean` is `False` or to `['a', 'list'][1]` if `boolean` is `True`

This can be abused by using conditions directly:

```
x = 1
print(['no', 'yes'][x > 0])
# yes
```

Answer (score 4):

Notice the following in python

```
>>> True == 1
True
>>> False == 0
True
```

as booleans *are* integers (in Python). so `[0,1,2][False] == 0` and `[0,1,2][True] == 1`

Comment: `[-5 - 256]` to be precise

Comment: Whether or not *any* integers are pre-allocated is an implementation detail that should not be counted on. Neither `True is 1` nor `False is 0` is guaranteed by the language, though `True == 1` and `False == 0` are.

Comment: @chepner For sake of completeness I think we don't even need to trust `True == 1` (and `False == 0`) for "boolean indexing" to work. Only `int(True) == 1` and `int(False) == 0` must stay true

Comment: `True == 1` can be guaranteed even if `bool` isn't a subclass of `int`; c.f. `1 == 1.0`.

Comment: In Python 2, `True` isn't a keyword, so something like `True = 1` can make `True is 1` true. Python 3 closed that loophole, though :)

Answer (score 1):

The boolean is either `True` or  `False`. If you have a list `mylist` then `mylist[0]` gets you the first element and `mylist[1]` gets you the second element.  `mylist[False]` means the same as `mylist[0]`. Now suppose  `mylist` contains `["list", "a"]`. Then `["list", "a"][False]` will give you the same value as `mylist[0]` which is `"list"`.

You are accustomed to seeing index notation (for example `[0]`) after the *name* of a list, as in `mylist[0]`. But it can just as well be used after a list literal, as in `["list", "a"][0]`.